# In Highcharts, how to set up title for each pyramid in a multi-pyramid chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Scenario is, a dynamic multi-pyramid chart, the pyramid numbers, pyramid position, screen size and other parameter could all vary. I am looking for a way to display the series name as title on top of each pyramid.

I've found out "how to set up title for each pie in multi-pie chart", by extending the current library:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.setTitle = function (titleOption) {
        var chart = this.chart,
            center = this.center || (this.yAxis && this.yAxis.center),
            labelBox,
            box,
            format;

        if (center && titleOption) {
            var centerX = center[0],
                centerY = center[1],
                diameter = center[2];

            box = {
                x: chart.plotLeft + centerX - 0.5 * diameter,
                y: chart.plotTop + centerY - 0.5 * diameter,
                width: diameter,
                height: diameter
            };

            format = titleOption.text || titleOption.format;
            format = Highcharts.format(format, this);

            if (this.title) {
                this.title.attr({
                    text: format
                });

            } else {
                this.title = this.chart.renderer.label(format)
                    .css(titleOption.style)
                    .add();
            }
            labelBox = this.title.getBBox();
            titleOption.width = labelBox.width;
            titleOption.height = labelBox.height;
            this.title.align(titleOption, null, box);
        }
    };
```

But I cannot apply a similar way to the pyramid. Thus my question is, are there any workarounds to set up title for each pyramid in a pyramid chart with more than one pyramid?

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/hsbepxo5/

Comment: Adding this option to pyramid should be almost the same. The problem is that you have small Highcharts bug connected with this topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5500
and Highcharts is calculating wrong center positions for your pyramid. Here you can see an example showing, that setTitle works partialy because of this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/hsbepxo5/1/ You may consider using renderer.text instead: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Hi, thanks a lot! I think you are right! I ended up using `renderer.text` as you mentioned. If you leave an answer down their, I'll mark it the right answer :D.

Comment: Happy to read that my idea worked for you :) I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this option to your chart should be almost the same as adding this option to pie charts.

```
  Highcharts.seriesTypes.pyramid.prototype.setTitle = function(titleOption) {
    var chart = this.chart,
      center = this.center || (this.yAxis && this.yAxis.center),
      labelBox,
      box,
      format;
    if (center && titleOption) {
      var centerX = center[0],
        centerY = center[1],
        diameter = center[2];
      centerY < 0 ? 2 * diameter : centerY
      box = {
        x: chart.plotLeft + centerX - 0.5 * diameter,
        y: centerY - 0.5 * diameter,
        width: diameter,
        height: diameter
      };

      format = titleOption.text || titleOption.format;
      format = Highcharts.format(format, this);

      if (this.title) {
        this.title.attr({
          text: format
        });

      } else {
        this.title = this.chart.renderer.label(format)
          .css(titleOption.style)
          .add();
      }
      labelBox = this.title.getBBox();
      titleOption.width = labelBox.width;
      titleOption.height = labelBox.height;
      this.title.align(titleOption, null, box);
    }
  };
```

I think that the problem is connected with small Highcharts bug, that is miscalculating center positions of your pyramid charts. Here you can find information about this issue on Highcharts github: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5500

Here you can see that setTitle works partialy because of this issue: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hsbepxo5/1/

I think that as a workaround you may consider using renderer.text instead of adding new functionality to your chart: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Best regards,